# Setting classpath for htmlunit

Tags: java, unix, classpath, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

I'm trying to code a simple program using the selenium browser automation framework and I need to use the library htmlunit.

Se here's my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
           driver.get("http://www.google.com");
           System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
     }
}
```

So it should print out "Google" but I keep getting: 
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver"

I'm running this in unix terminal, so this is what I'm typing in to run it

```
export CLASSPATH=selenium-2.9.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.9.0.jar:selenium-2.9.0/libs/htmlunit-2.9.jar
javac -cp $CLASSPATH Test.java
java Test
```

And then I get the error... So any suggestions? I seem to load both libraries, but I know that I'm messing something up with the htmlunit library...

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the classpath when you run the test, too, not just during compilation.

(Also, IIRC the standalone jar contains htmlunit already; you might not need to explicitly include the htmlunit jar.)

Comment: I didn't spot the missing cp on run +1